# CSS :focus Selector with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I have numerous buttons which I create with 'button' tag.I'm using :focus Selector to change button's color to yellow from another color when I click on it.

Now,I have Javascript code which make the same thing (change background color of button),only difference is that it's connected to input.

here is example:

```js
function coloringButton() {
  let myInput = document.getElementById("numbers");
  let lastChar = myInput.value.slice(-1);

  switch (lastChar) {
    case '1':
      document.getElementById("Two").style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
      document.getElementById("One").style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
      break;

    case '2':
      document.getElementById("One").style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
      document.getElementById("Two").style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
#One,
#Two {
  background-color: gray;
}

#One:focus,
#Two:focus {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numbers" name="numbers" autocomplete="off" onkeyup='coloringButton()'>
<button type="button" id='One'>
    <span>1</span>
    </button>
<button type="button" id='Two'>
    <span>2</span>
    </button>
```

When I click on button first,:focus is working.
My problem is that after running the javascript code with the input (enter chars to input),The :focus selector not working anymore if I try to click some button.
Is there an option so that the :focus effect will return to work after that javascript code without using onclick event with javascript?

Comment: Styles that are added explicitly to the `.style` property take precedence over styles from CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.style` property takes precedence over styles that come from CSS.

You can use the `!important` flag in the CSS styles to override this.

```js
function coloringButton() {
  let myInput = document.getElementById("numbers");
  let lastChar = myInput.value.slice(-1);
  switch (lastChar) {
    case '1':
      document.getElementById("Two").style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
      document.getElementById("One").style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
      break;

    case '2':
      document.getElementById("One").style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
      document.getElementById("Two").style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
      break;

  }
}
```

```css
#One {
  background-color: gray;
}

#One:focus {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}

#Two {
  background-color: gray;
}

#Two:focus {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numbers" name="numbers" autocomplete="off" onkeyup='coloringButton()'>
<button type="button" id='One'>
    <span>1</span>
    </button>
<button type="button" id='Two'>
    <span>2</span>
    </button>
```

Comment: Thx!Another little question  about it if you can answer: Can the selector somehow disable the outcome of some function in javascript?For example  :focus selector disable coloringButton() outcome so when I press on button the other button changes to default style.

Comment: No, but the function can check `document.activeElement` to determine which element is focused, and change what it does accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I would add an extra case to your function:

```
 case '':
      document.getElementById("One").style = null;
      document.getElementById("Two").style = null;
      break;
```

This will cancel changes done to buttons by js and return to CSS styling leaving everything else as it is.
Also it prevents from a scenario where there is '1' in the input field which changes te color of button1 to yellow, and you focus on button2 by hand also changing its color to yellow.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a6dY.png)